# How to set Keystore using Groovy script

Tags: groovy, soapui

I need to set related link to certificate. But in WS-Security Configuration - Keystores I can set only absolute path. How I can do this using scripts?

Comment: May be you want add more details to the question? what do you mean by related link? You may add screen shot as well.

Comment: relative path like /graphics/image.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import com.eviware.soapui.settings.SSLSettings
import com.eviware.soapui.SoapUI 

// set
SoapUI.settings.setString( SSLSettings.KEYSTORE, pathToKeystore )
SoapUI.settings.setString( SSLSettings.KEYSTORE_PASSWORD, keystorePassword )

// get
SoapUI.settings.getString( SSLSettings.KEYSTORE, "value to return if there is no such setting set" )
```

https://www.soapui.org/scripting-properties/tips-tricks.html

Answer (score 0):

```
import com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.wss.crypto.CryptoType

// 1. Specify the path to your keystore
def keystorePath = "C:\\pathToKeystore\\your_keystore.jks"
// To use a relative path
//def keystorePath = context.expand('${projectDir}') + "\\report\\your_keystore.jks"

// 2. Add a keystore
testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.wssContainer.addCrypto(keystorePath,"keystore_password",CryptoType.KEYSTORE) //path, password, cryptoType

// 3. Get the status in the log
log.info(testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.wssContainer.getCryptoByName("your_keystore.jks").getStatus()) // specify the name of your keystore
```

This code is working as per your requirement.